# Apply local changes to newer versions of a GitHub project

Tags: git

Maybe an easy question, but I am not sure where to search and it seems as if the default `git` workflows on their website and their books do not cover this scenario. (But maybe I am wrong and I don't see the forest for the git trees...)

I am using a project from GitHub. This is a very cool project and I would like to make it even cooler by adding some local changes - let's call them "branding". (It's more than that, but branding is good as an example here, as it's basically the same situation).
Of course, the developers are not interested in my local modifications, so they will never be included in their repository.
I have used their version 1.0, made my modifications there, created a new branch (`local-changes`) and committed that. (Actually there are two commits with two different changes.)

What should I do now, when there's version 2.0, 3.0 and so on are available?
(Let's assume that the parts modified are not changed in the newer versions, as things get more complicated then and there might not be an easy answer anymore.)

I don't assume that I can just merge both branches, as I just would like to apply my minor changes to the newer versions and merging the whole branches would probably generate many conflicts, as many items have changed between my branch based on V 1.0 and the current upstream V 5.5. (Or am I wrong?)
So what to do?
What would be the correct `git` workflow for this scenario?

Comment: Easiest option is `git pull --rebase`, and you can make rebasing the default with `git config branch.local-changes.rebase true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a variety options when taking upstream changes, but probably want to look at one of

merge their branch into yours and fix any conflicts (perhaps fixes on both sides)

```bash
git merge other-branch
```

rebase your commits (potentially fixes to your commits)

```bash
git checkout branch  # from your source or otherwise isolate changes
git rebase other-branch
```

cherry-pick your commits (potentially fixes to your commits)

```bash
git checkout other-branch  # then perhaps make a new local copy
git cherry-pick commit1 commit2  # your local commits
```

The first is likely the most sustainable, but if you are making releases to follow upstream releases, branch and rebase may be best

Comment: But there are many, many changes between my local changes branch (created with V 1.0) and the latest upstream commit. Will `git` be so smart to detect which changes to include in the merge (i.e. apply all changes from upstream but apply the two changes form my local commits? Or will there be many, many conflicts? Then, `cherry-pick` seems to be more straight-forward. But I think I still don't understand merging correctly, right?

Comment: And what do you mean by "fixes to my commits" or "fixes on both sides". So you refer to possible merge conflicts?

Comment: ah, yes, or specifically the source of the merge conflicts!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you using cherry-pick to double commit the changes to newer version 2.0 or 3.0.

Since you have mentioned, there are two commits for branding on branch `local-changes`, let's assume they(the 2 commits) are called `branding-commit-1, branding-commit-1`

Remember hash of the above 2 commits, then go to the branch of newer version you want to apply the changes. (Let's assume you want to apply branding changes to version3)

```
git checkout version3-branch
git cherry-pick branding-commit-1 branding-commit-2


# Below are only necessary if you want to push the changes to version3 remote
#git push origin version3-branch
```

Comment: That sounds correct to me. But I'd like to understand the other answers first, before marking an answer as correct. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, rebase is also a good choice.